# wordpress wp_get_current_user data not displaying in jason-api

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I want to display a WordPress logged in user ID and email in another website so, I'm using the wordpress`json-api` plugin to create an api but it's not working.
When I hit a direct link, it displays data as:

```
"{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"admin@admin.com\"}"
```

But when I use `json_decode` and print data, it displays:

```
string(22) "{"id":0,"email":false}"
```

api code

```
public function get_loggedin_user_details() {
    global $user;
    global $wpdb, $json_api;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $myObj->id = $current_user->ID;
    $myObj->email = $current_user->user_email;
    $logedin_userid = json_encode($myObj);
    return $logedin_userid;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the process to get the logged in user id on WP:

1. install [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin for rest-API authentication(**read plugin description**) 
   [image]
2. pass the login token you receive from the plugin to the
   route you created as Header: Authorization 
   [image]
3. create you custom Rest-API Route like this:

   ```
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
   register_rest_route( 'your_custom_route/v2', '/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', array(
       'methods' => 'POST',
       'callback' => 'rest_api_custom_func',
       ) );
   } );

   function rest_api_custom_func(){ 
       global $user;
       global $wpdb;
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
       $myObj->id = $current_user->ID;
       $myObj->email = $current_user->user_email;
       $logedin_userid = json_encode($myObj);
       return $logedin_userid;     }
   ```
4. write your own function as a callback function on rest-api route
   :*rest_api_custom_func*
5. you can do whatever you want with your custom callback function

note: no need for any other plugin, use the built-in [Wordpress Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Comment: its not working for send logged in user information.

Comment: did you do all steps of this process?

Comment: can you please explain "pass the login token you receive from the plugin to this route as Header: Authorization" this point

Comment: gaurav.rawat12 is my skype

Comment: i added you, massage me when you have time

Comment: I can confirm this solution works, I just implemented it after failing with OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You are not authenticating your request, so the request is not logged, resulting in ID 0 and no email.

WP rest api provides a cookie authentication method, but there also plugins, you can read more on how-to here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to point out something that maybe was just overlooked.

Your initial value is escaped...  "{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"admin@admin.com\"}" and has quotes around the outside.  It's not a proper json string.

Should be:  {"id":1,"email":"admin@admin.com"}